# How to type-cast as template member function parameter?

Tags: c++, casting, overloading, member-functions

I implemented the class template `writer`. The `writer` has template member variable `s_`. The type of `s_` is `Stream`. `writer` expects that `Stream` has a member function that can called with parameters `const char* buf` and `size_t len`.

Here is the first version of `writer`:

```
// clang++ -Wconversion test.cpp

#include <cstddef>
#include <ostream>

template <class F> struct size_arg_type;

template <typename Ret, typename Cls, typename T1, typename T2>
struct size_arg_type<Ret (Cls::*)(T1, T2)> {
    using type = T2;
};

template <typename Stream>
struct writer {
    writer(Stream& s):s_(s) {}

    void write(const char* buf, size_t len) {
        // The type of 2nd parameter depends on Stream
        s_.write(buf, len);
    }

    Stream& s_;
};

struct user_stream1 {
    void write(const char*, size_t) {}
};

struct user_stream2 {
    void write(const char*, std::streamsize) {}
};

struct user_stream3 {
    void write(const char*, size_t) {}
    void write() {}
};

#include <sstream>

int main() {
    {   // size_type is size_t
        user_stream1 s;
        writer w(s);
        char buf[] = "123";
        w.write(buf, sizeof(buf));
    }
    {   // size_type is std::streamsize
        user_stream2 s;
        writer w(s);
        char buf[] = "123";
        w.write(buf, sizeof(buf));
    }
#if 1
    {   // size_type is size_t but has overloaded member function
        user_stream3 s;
        writer w(s);
        char buf[] = "123";
        w.write(buf, sizeof(buf));
    }
#endif
    {   // size_type is std::streamsize return type is std::ostream&
        std::stringstream s;
        writer w(s);
        char buf[] = "123";
        w.write(buf, sizeof(buf));
    }
}
```

Running demo: https://wandbox.org/permlink/JtEHDG3plWxe4vwB

If I set `-Wconversion` flags to clang++, I got the following warnings.

```
clang++ -std=c++17 -Wconversion test.cpp 
test.cpp:18:23: warning: implicit conversion changes signedness: 'size_t' (aka 'unsigned long') to
      'std::streamsize' (aka 'long') [-Wsign-conversion]
        s_.write(buf, len);
           ~~~~~      ^~~
test.cpp:50:11: note: in instantiation of member function 'writer<user_stream2>::write' requested here
        w.write(buf, sizeof(buf));
          ^
test.cpp:18:23: warning: implicit conversion changes signedness: 'size_t' (aka 'unsigned long') to
      'std::streamsize' (aka 'long') [-Wsign-conversion]
        s_.write(buf, len);
           ~~~~~      ^~~
test.cpp:64:11: note: in instantiation of member function 'writer<std::__cxx11::basic_stringstream<char>
      >::write' requested here
        w.write(buf, sizeof(buf));
          ^
2 warnings generated.

Compilation finished at Wed May  1 09:37:37
```

I tried to find a way to suppress the warnings without pragma.
I came up with `static_cast` approach. In order to do `static_cast`, I need to know the 2nd parameter type.

So I implemented some parameter type extractor:

```
// clang++ -std=c++17 -Wconversion test.cpp

#include <cstddef>
#include <ostream>

template <class F> struct size_arg_type;

template <typename Ret, typename Cls, typename T1, typename T2>
struct size_arg_type<Ret (Cls::*)(T1, T2)> {
    using type = T2;
};

template <typename Stream>
struct writer {
    writer(Stream& s):s_(s) {}

    void write(const char* buf, size_t len) {
        write_impl(&Stream::write, buf, len);
    }

    template <typename Write>
    void write_impl(Write, const char* buf, size_t len)
    {
        s_.write(buf, static_cast<typename size_arg_type<Write>::type>(len));
    }

    Stream& s_;
};

struct user_stream1 {
    void write(const char*, size_t) {}
};

struct user_stream2 {
    void write(const char*, std::streamsize) {}
};

struct user_stream3 {
    void write(const char*, size_t) {}
    void write() {}
};

#include <sstream>

int main() {
    {   // size_type is size_t
        user_stream1 s;
        writer w(s);
        char buf[] = "123";
        w.write(buf, sizeof(buf));
    }
    {   // size_type is std::streamsize
        user_stream2 s;
        writer w(s);
        char buf[] = "123";
        w.write(buf, sizeof(buf));
    }
#if 1
    {   // size_type is size_t but has overloaded member function
        user_stream3 s;
        writer w(s);
        char buf[] = "123";
        w.write(buf, sizeof(buf));
    }
#endif
    {   // size_type is std::streamsize return type is std::ostream&
        std::stringstream s;
        writer w(s);
        char buf[] = "123";
        w.write(buf, sizeof(buf));
    }
}
```

It works as I expected. However In the case `user_stream3` that has overloaded `write()` member function, compile error is happened.

Running demo: https://wandbox.org/permlink/TDPlQ3nXzIKjSlhY

In order to get specific overload of member functions, I need to know full member function pointer type. However, it is unpredictable.

```
    clang++ -std=c++17 -Wconversion test.cpp 
    test.cpp:18:9: error: no matching member function for call to 'write_impl'
            write_impl(&Stream::write, buf, len);
            ^~~~~~~~~~
    test.cpp:63:11: note: in instantiation of member function 'writer<user_stream3>::write' requested here
            w.write(buf, sizeof(buf));
              ^
    test.cpp:22:10: note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'Write'
        void write_impl(Write, const char* buf, size_t len)
             ^
    1 error generated.

    Compilation exited abnormally with code 1 at Wed May  1 09:48:42
```

Is there any good way to know the size-type, or to suppress warning without pragma?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to require all the `write` functions in your stream classes to have the same parameter types?  Otherwise someone might want to create a `write(const void *, short);` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When taking the address of the write function in your second version, it doesn't know which overload to take the address of.  You need to sufficiently constrain your template parameters so that the overloads aren't ambigous:

```
template <typename Stream>
struct writer {
    writer(Stream& s):s_(s) {}

    void write(const char* buf, size_t len) {
        write_impl(&Stream::write, buf, len);
    }

    template <typename Ret, typename Cls, typename T1, typename T2>
    void write_impl(Ret (Cls::*)(T1, T2), const char* buf, size_t len)
    {
        s_.write(buf, static_cast<T2>(len));
    }

    Stream& s_;
};
```

https://wandbox.org/permlink/7Qb6xAoUQPRz3o2u

However, this will still fail if there are multiple 2-argument `write` functions. In which case you would have to either find more constraints (e.g. first arg has to be `const char *`) or just require a specific signature from the user's code.

Comment: Thank you! This is something I need.